# Dotnet core identityserver4 reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, .net-core, identityserver4, nginx-reverse-proxy

Hi everybody I have a problem with my reverse proxy configuration for my dotnet core application. My problem is that when I am using identityserver discovery endpoint the port number is missing from the end of my url.

I have a request for the discorvery document to
https://:8421/.well-known/openid-configuration
and the response is the following and the problem here is that the clients of the authentication service are using the document as a base for verification, using jwks_uri property from the response, the url listed in that property has the missing port number, so the clients cant call the openId configuration.

```
 {
    "issuer": "https://<servername>",
    "jwks_uri": "https://<servername>/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks",
    "authorization_endpoint": "https://<servername>/connect/authorize",
    "token_endpoint": "https://<servername>/connect/token",
    "userinfo_endpoint": "https://<servername>/connect/userinfo",
    "end_session_endpoint": "https://<servername>/connect/endsession",
    "check_session_iframe": "https://<servername>/connect/checksession",
    "revocation_endpoint": "https://<servername>/connect/revocation",
    "introspection_endpoint": "https://<servername>/connect/introspect",
    "device_authorization_endpoint": "https://<servername>/connect/deviceauthorization"
}
```

expected result for endpoint config:

```
  {
    "jwks_uri": "https://<servername>:<port>/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks",
  }
```

In my dotnet app I setup the reverse proxy settings

```
  services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ForwardedHeaders =
                         ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor |
                         ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedHost |
                         ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;

            options.ForwardLimit = 2;  //Limit number of proxy hops trusted
            options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
            options.KnownProxies.Clear();
        });
  app.UseForwardedHeaders();
```

nginx config is the following

```
server {
    listen <ip>:8421 ssl;
    server_name _; 

    ssl_certificate    <certPath> ;
    ssl_certificate_key <certPath>;
 

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8421; 

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 8421;
    }
}
```

Before updateing to Identityserver 4 4.0 it had the Public origin property but it became deprecated with 4.0. Now instead it is using the dotnet baseurl.

In the http pipeline I also logged all the headers from the request and got this result:

```
2020-07-03 11:40:15.109 +00:00;[INF];Cache-Control--no-cache Connection--upgrade Accept--*/* Accept-Encoding--gzip, deflate, br Host--<hostName> User-Agent--PostmanRuntime/7.26.1 X-Real-IP--<ip> X-Original-Proto--http X-Forwarded-Host--<domainName with port> X-Forwarded-Port--8421 Postman-Token--44dc6573-71eb-4b36-8b2a-9768d71e5b64 X-Original-For--<ip address> ;;
```

Comment: Have you considered using NGINX instead of rollling your own reverse proxy app? Maybe overkill but maybe a better idea than rolling your own.

Comment: This is the app behind the nginx proxy. I was asking whether how was it possible to confiure nginx to work with identityserver

Comment: Whoops thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add the port also to the nginx configuration. Setting the X-Forwarded-Host to $host was not enough also had to add the **$proxy_port** as well

The working confiugration for proxy

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$proxy_port;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the host is listening on non-default ports (not 80 for http and not 443 for https), use **$http_host** instead of **$host** to set the *Host* as shown below.

Change 
`change proxy_set_header Host $host;`

to

`proxy_set_header Host $http_host;`